# How to add layout in blade in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

This is my output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lYwB.png)
I created one layout in layouts/member.blade.php and i used in the member/add-single-trade/index.blade.php than content are blank nd show only member layout content
This is member layout

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<style >
  .sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width:100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
.fa-caret-down {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

</style>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

@yield('content');

  <div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Search</a>
</div>

  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
} 
  </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

This is blade of member/add-single-trade/index.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.member')
@section('content')

<form method="post" action="{{route('member.add-single-trade.store')}}">
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
   Tradedate:<input type="datetime-local" name="tradedate" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
   Traderate:<input type="text" name="traderate" class="form-control">
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
</form>
@endsection
```

How can i show member layout sidebar in index.blade.php?
I need help

Comment: comment `javascript` and try

Comment: Again check my question -@AlexanderVillalobos

Answer (score 0):

if youre using laravel 4. change your @section('content') @endsection to

```
@section('content')
   ///code here
@stop
```